# How does the Spell Compendium change the healer spell list?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, healing

The healer class from the *Miniature's Handbook* has on its spell list the *close wounds* spell. The *Spell Compendium* doesn't list the *close wounds* spell as a healer spell. Should a healer that's in a campaign that uses the *Spell Compendium* use the older version of the *close wounds* spell from the *MH* or the newer *SpC* version? If the newer one, what spell level should the *close wounds* spell be for a healer?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on the question here. Are you planning to use the version of the *close wounds* spell from the *MH* or the *SpC*? If the former, you may be interested in this question about [primary sources](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56771/8610) and [this answer's list of books](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36990/8610) that include release dates. If you're just wondering why the *MH* would have the spell *close wounds* have a casting time of 1 swift action, I guess the site could try to answer that, but I'm kind of left wondering why such an answer would be needed.

Comment: My player would like to play Healer from Miniatures Handbook and the spell from MH has casting time of 1 swing action and allows to be cast in off-turn (which conflicts with SRD about difference between immediate and swift action, as swift action cannot be cast in off-turn.

Comment: O, I get that, but I'm unsure of how you're managing source priority. According to the rules, typically a game element outside of the core rules that's printed later takes precedence over a game element printed earlier that possesses the same name (see the links in my previous comment). You've both the *MH* and the *SpC*, so most folks would default to the later-printed *SpC*. Could the question make clear why there's resistance to that? (Or is that me accidentally answering the question?) (Also, the site uses code format only for actual code; use `>` for quotations instead.)

Comment: Thank you very much, the reason I neglect to to this is because the description for SpC doesn't mention Healer class (only Cleric) and the first paragraph differs from the original one. I'm not sure if I can use the same rules to Healer (class from MH2) as to Cleric - but the spell name remains the same, so what should I do?

Comment: Aha! Okay. That explains the confusion. Then the question is, essentially, *Does the* Spell Compendium *remove from the healer's spell list the* close wounds *spell?* Is that right? If that's the case, you may be interested in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/136093/8610).

Comment: Healer is not listed in SpC at all as it this class didn't exist, although there are spell lists for many spellcasting classes, so I don't know what to do right now :( Can i go with a version from SpC and use it for Healer from MH2 although it doesn't mention Healer at all?

Comment: I've just seen that the spell level is also different (MH-Cleric3, Healer3, Spc - Cleric2

Comment: Really, [click this link](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/136093/8610) for information on dealing with classes the *Spell Compendium* doesn't directly address. I recommend updating this question to something like *How does using the* Spell Compendium *change the healer's spell list?*

Comment: Thank you very much for this topic, I've read it and it is very helpful, maybe I should just go with the versions from SpC and trust that they are also valid for Healer class

Comment: I made a *massive* edit to this question to reflect this conversation. If the question's no longer asking what you want answered, please edit it further or roll it back. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Spell Compendium* deals exclusively with spells used by the classes and prestige classes introduced in the *Player’s Handbook* and *Dungeon Master’s Guide*,

<sup>(*Spell Compendium* pg. 3)</sup>

Since healer is from *Miniatures Handbook*, *Spell Compendium* ignores it and does not list it on any spells. Despite this, it continues to use all the spells *Miniatures Handbook* listed on its spell list, and *Spell Compendium* furthermore recommends that DMs augment the healer spell list, saying to

> Add spells concerned with healing, providing protections, removing affliction, and providing for needs. In particular, add higher-level versions of spells the healer can already cast, such as *mass restoration*.

<sup>(*Spell Compendium* pg. 3)</sup>

Furthermore, the Sources sidebar on page 4 says

> If you have been playing with a spell we’ve picked up and revised for this book, you should strongly consider updating your character or campaign to the new version.
>
> [...]
>
> Most of the changes we made to previously published material we made to create an improved version of that material—to help out spells that were formerly suboptimal choices,

<sup>(*Spell Compendium* pg. 4)</sup>

All of this means that the fact that healer is not listed in *close wounds* on page 48 should be ignored—healer isn’t listed anywhere in *Spell Compendium*, for any spell. Nonetheless, this is the same *close wounds* as in *Miniatures Handbook*, just updated, and so since *close wounds* is a healer spell (per *Miniatures Handbook*, which covers the healer while *Spell Compendium* doesn’t), the healer would use the updated *Spell Compendium* version. Even if *Miniatures Handbook* didn’t make *close wounds* a healer spell, the description on page 3 certainly says that it should be one anyway, just like *mass restoration*.

And since the *Miniatures Handbook* version of *close wounds* is a 3rd-level spell for both cleric and healer, the *Spell Compendium* version, a 2nd-level spell for the cleric, should also be so for the healer.